# Optimize a function with not-full knowledge of gradient

Tags: convex-optimization, global-optimization

I want to optimize the following function:

$$
argmin_{x} f(x) = g(x) + h(x)
$$

, where I can get $\nabla_xg(x)$, but cannot calculate $\nabla_xh(x)$.

The derivative-free method, such as the Hill climbing method, works well, but I wonder whether I can make use of $\nabla_xg(x)$.

Comment: This question is far too general. Look at the trivial case $g \equiv 0$.

Comment: @DieterKadelka I do not fully agree (see my answer), although I also see that a bit more detail would have been helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Problems of this type may be solved with splitting methods. One very popular case if the *proximal gradient method*. If $h$ is convex and lower-semicontinuous and if you are able to caluculate the proximal map, namely
$$\operatorname{prox}_{\lambda h}(x) = \operatorname{argmin}_y \tfrac12\|y-x\|_2^2 + \lambda h(y)$$
you can iterate
$$x^{k+1} = \operatorname{prox}_{\lambda h}(x^k - \lambda\nabla g(x^k)).$$
If $g$ is convex and $\nabla g$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $L$ this iteration will converge to a solution if $0<\lambda < 2/L$. There are extensions for non-convex problems as well…

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, $h(x)$ is black-box, so I think I cannot calculate the proximal map...

Comment: Well, in this case I don't know any method that can take advantage of a gradient of a part of the objective…